# new window into Electron vuejs app with router mode hash

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-router

In context of Electron vuejs app, I need to use many window in my application like modals in a website.

For that I created a service for managing window/modal in my application.

In the begin of building my Electron app I use a vue-router with History mode.

In this mode router all my window run like a charm

**BUT**
My electron production environment not working because I use History router mode.

*Now I use a Hash mode router ([more explain here](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/commonIssues.html#blank-screen-on-builds-but-works-fine-on-serve))*

and my production environment run like a charm

**BUT** now (and this is the main in this post!)
All the new contents windows created are the same.

It is the first component url mounted because the associate url is "/".
The router doesn't care about whole URL path like this : http://localhost:8080/employee/edit/20
Solely that : http://localhost:8080/

this is my code that launch the window(modal) :

```
createModal(type, params = null, event)
{
    this.browserWindow = this.createBrowserWindow()
    this.setURL(type, params)
    this.browserWindow.show()
    
    event.sender.send("modal-end", "yes")
}

createBrowserWindow()
{
    return new BrowserWindow({width: 650, height: 800, show: false, frame: true,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            plugins: true,
            nodeIntegration: (process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION)},
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            // contextIsolation: false
    });
}

    if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    {
        console.log('here modal url')
        console.log(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL + url)
        
        this.browserWindow.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL + url)
        // this.browserWindow.loadURL("https://www.google.com");
        if (!process.env.IS_TEST) this.browserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    }
    else
    {
        createProtocol('app')
        this.browserWindow.loadURL('app://./index.html')
        // this.browserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
        
    }
```

*Do you have an idea how to create a new window electron in vue framework and vue-router HASH mode
that display the contents of other component vue than first mounted component app ?*

**Technical information :**

- Electron : 11.2.0
- Vuejs : 2.6.12
- dev env : Webpack Dev Server (webpack : 4.45.0)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem and after hours of searching I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue of the new Electron window containing the whole app and not the new page I specified in the route. I don't know how you have your App.vue set up, but in my case the problem was that the app page needs to be changed to just contain `<router-view></router-view>` and then you need to move everything else to a different page and point the router to that page. Like this:

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'my-app'
  }
</script>
```

Main.js

```html
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <Header />  
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />   
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './Header.vue'
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne.vue"
import ComponentTwo from './ComponentTwo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'main',
  components: {
    Header, 
    ComponentOne,
    ComponentTwo
  }
}
</script>
```

Router.js

```js
import { createWebHashHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'main',
      component: require('@/components/Main.vue').default
    },
    {
      path: '/set',
      name: 'Settings',
      component: require('@/components/Settings.vue').default
    }  
  ]
})
export default router
```

In index.js, wherever you set up your menus:

```js
{
  label: 'Settings',
  click() {         
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ 
      width: 800, 
      height: 600, 
      webPreferences: { 
          nodeIntegration: true,  
          contextIsolation: false
      }
    })
    win.on('close', function () { win = null })
    const setURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? 'http://localhost:9080/#/set'
    : `file://${__dirname}/index.html#/set`     
    win.loadURL(setURL)
    win.show()
  }
}
```

Note: These web preference options are a security concern for some projects, please check: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security

Answer (score 0):

use a callback function when importing components
from:

```
{
     path: '/',
     name: 'main',
     component: require('@/components/Main.vue').default
},
```

to:

```
{
      path: '/',
      name: 'main',
      component: () => require('@/components/Main.vue').default
},
```

...enter code additional here...